# Cassandra database session reuse in AWS Lambda (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cassandra, connection-pooling, aws-lambda

I am trying to reuse a Cassandra cluster session for subsequent AWS Lambda function calls. I've successfully implemented it in Java, but reusing the session in the python gets the lambda invocation timed out (the first call which actually performs the initialization is ok).

From the CloudWatch logs I can see I get a `Heartbeat failed for connection`. It looks to me that the session is not able to communicate while idle, and that it gets in an inconsistent state in which is not able to resume the connection. Trying longer or shorter `idle_heartbeat_interval` than the function timeout in fact doesn't have any impact on the outcome.

Here is the structure of my lambda function (omitted some code for brevity):

```
import logging
from cassandra_client import CassandraClient

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#   State of the initialization phase
flag = False

#   Cassandra instance
cassandra = None

def handle_request(event, context):

    global flag, logger, cassandra

    logger.info('Function started. Flag: %s' % (str(flag), ))

    if not flag:
        logger.info('Initialization...')
        try:
            cassandra = CassandraClient()

            #   ...

            flag = True

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Cannot perform initialization: '+e.message)
            exit(-1)

    #   Process the request ...
    return 'OK'
```

Just for completeness, that's how I create the connection with the cluster:

```
def _connect(self, seed_nodes=default_seed_nodes, port=default_port):
    self.cluster = Cluster(seed_nodes, port=port)
    self.metadata = self.cluster.metadata
    self.session = self.cluster.connect()
    # ...
```

Is there some driver configuration detail, python lambda behavior I am not aware of that prevents the session to be reused?

I do think AWS Lambda is a really great tool, but not having much control over the execution can be somehow confusing for certain aspects. Any suggestion is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can just initialize the cluster at the module level and then use it in your handler.  There is no need to use ``flag`` to control that.  However, that is just a style point, I don't think that is causing a problem.  What do your logs say?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it would be more clear for sure. I've looked into the CloudWatch logs, and each request ends with a `Task timed out after 300.00 seconds`. Depending on the client configuration I tried, I got also a `Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)`, and the aforementioned `Heartbeat failed for connection`. It is not always consistent in the outcome.

Comment: Is you Lambda function in a VPC?  If so, is the Cassandra cluster in the same VPC?

Comment: Yes, it runs in a VPC. I have no problem communicating with the cluster if I set up the session in each execution. This issue shows up only if it has to re-use a previously set up connection.

Comment: Also, connection reuse using the Java driver does not cause the same issue.

Comment: *"It looks to me that the session is not able to communicate while idle"*  That part is correct.  The container is "frozen" between invocations and then "thawed" again when the next one arrives.

Comment: Does this mean that we have a different behavior using Java which leaves the container in a somehow active state?

Comment: I am trying to figure out if it is caused by configuration, or by some implementation detail of the driver.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I just posted an answer to compare the different behaviors of the Java and Python environments. Do you agree with what I got as result?

Comment: Alse @garnaat, do you agree with what I got as result?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can state that this issue is cause by a different behavior of lambda when using the Python execution environment w.r.t. Java.

I had time to set up a simple lambda function, implemented both in Java ad Python. The function simply spawns a thread which prints the current time in a while loop. The question was: will the thread in the Java implementation continue printing even after the lambda function has returned, and conversely, will the Python thread stop instead? The answer is yes in both cases: the java thread continues printing till the timeout configured, while python will stop as soon as the lambda function returns.

The CloudWatch log for the Java version confirms that:

```
09:55:21 START RequestId: b70e732b-e476-11e6-b2bb-e11a0dd9b311 Version: $LATEST
09:55:21 Function started: 1485510921351
09:55:21 Pre function call: 1485510921351
09:55:21 Background function: 1485510921352
09:55:21 Background function: 1485510921452
09:55:21 Background function: 1485510921552
09:55:21 Background function: 1485510921652
09:55:21 Background function: 1485510921752
09:55:21 Post function call: 1485510921852
09:55:21 Background function: 1485510921853
09:55:21 END RequestId: b70e732b-e476-11e6-b2bb-e11a0dd9b311
09:55:21 REPORT RequestId: b70e732b-e476-11e6-b2bb-e11a0dd9b311 Duration: 523.74 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 31 MB
09:55:21 Background function: 1485510921953
09:55:22 Background function: 1485510922053
...
```

While in the Python version:

```
09:01:04 START RequestId: 21ccc71e-e46f-11e6-926b-6b46f85c9c69 Version: $LATEST
09:01:04 Function started: 2017-01-27 09:01:04.189819
09:01:04 Pre function call: 2017-01-27 09:01:04.189849
09:01:04 background_call function: 2017-01-27 09:01:04.194368
09:01:04 background_call function: 2017-01-27 09:01:04.294617
09:01:04 background_call function: 2017-01-27 09:01:04.394843
09:01:04 background_call function: 2017-01-27 09:01:04.495100
09:01:04 background_call function: 2017-01-27 09:01:04.595349
09:01:04 Post function call: 2017-01-27 09:01:04.690483
09:01:04 END RequestId: 21ccc71e-e46f-11e6-926b-6b46f85c9c69
09:01:04 REPORT RequestId: 21ccc71e-e46f-11e6-926b-6b46f85c9c69 Duration: 500.99 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 8 MB
```

Here's the code of the two functions:

**Python**

```
import thread
import datetime
import time


def background_call():
    while True:
        print 'background_call function: %s' % (datetime.datetime.now(), )
        time.sleep(0.1)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print 'Function started: %s' % (datetime.datetime.now(), )

    print 'Pre function call: %s' % (datetime.datetime.now(), )
    thread.start_new_thread(background_call, ())
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print 'Post function call: %s' % (datetime.datetime.now(), )

    return 'Needs more cowbell!'
```

**Java**

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.*;


public class BackgroundTest implements RequestHandler<RequestClass, ResponseClass> {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }

    public ResponseClass handleRequest(RequestClass requestClass, Context context) {
        System.out.println("Function started: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("Pre function call: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Background function: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Post function call: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        return new ResponseClass("Needs more cowbell!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you've spent any more time troubleshooting the python driver after this?

Comment: @Geotob Unfortunately I did not. I failed getting feedback from AWS about this and gave up the idea.

Comment: Thanks @riccamini, I played around with it yesterday and think I got it working:)

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar issue in the `cassandra-driver` FAQs, where WSGI applications won't work with a global connection pool:

> Depending on your application process model, it may be forking after driver Session is created. Most IO reactors do not handle this, and problems will manifest as timeouts. [Here][1]

This at least got me on the right track to check the available connection classes: it turns out that `cassandra.io.twistedreactor.TwistedConnection` works pretty well on AWS Lambda.

All in all the code looks something like this:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.io.twistedreactor import TwistedConnection
import time


SESSION = Cluster([...], connection_class=TwistedConnection).connect()


def run(event, context):
    t0 = time.time()
    x = list(SESSION.execute('SELECT * FROM keyspace.table'))  # Ensure query actually evaluated
    print('took', time.time() - t0)
```

You will need to install `twisted` in your venv though.

I ran this overnight on 1-min crontab and have only seen a few connection errors (up to 2 in an hour), so overall quite happy with the solution.

Also I haven't tested `eventlet` and `gevent` based connections, because I can't have them monkey patching my applications, and I also didn't feel like compiling `libev` to use on lambda. Someone else might want to try though.

Don't forget to 
 http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/faq.html#why-do-connections-or-io-operations-timeout-in-my-wsgi-application